# Encoding special characters in ISO-8859-1

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

How – or “ or € is encoded in ISO-8859-1?

I have referred this document http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html but did not find any encoding for – or “ or €.

Comment: " (22) and - (2D) are the same as ASCII. € is not included in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The Euro sign is contained in **ISO-8859-15** - but it would be advisable to switch to **UTF-8** instead which gives you all the characters and lots of special chars, too.

Comment: You probably should give more context in your question. Why do you ask? What kind of legacy application are you working on? In which language? Where is the data (what kind of database, what size)? So **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: @griddoor that's – ([U+2013](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)) not a regular ASCII minus, and “ ([U+201C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201C/index.htm)) not a regular ASCII double quote.  Neither of these exist in ISO-8859-1, either (or in ISO-8859-15, for what it's worth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Don't*** use ISO8859-1 (in particular, because it may lack encoding for the characters you want). Use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), as most applications do today. See [UTF8everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Read wikipage on [Euro sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign). It tells you that € is the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org)  U+20AC, represented in UTF-8 with the  0xE2 0x82 0xAC codes, i.e. in C octal string syntax: `"\342\202\254"`

<sup>On my Debian/Linux I am using the [gucharmap](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gnome/gucharmap) character map application to find such encodings. You have lots of resources on UTF-8 on the web: [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/), [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm), [here](http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/), etc...</sup>

In a software that you write or improve in 2015, there is no reason to use ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8

For historical reference only the Euro sign € did not exist in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (because it appeared in 1985, and the [Euro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro), planned by the [Maastricht treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maastricht_Treaty) of 1992, arrived in 2002) but only in [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) but you should **use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)**

If you persist (wrongly) on using ISO8859-x *deprecated encoding* your users will be upset, because more and more applications, clients, browsers, ... are not using it anymore. The world has switched to UTF-8, and it also gives the advantage of being able to display many alphabets (including cyrillic or arabic) and glyphs.

If you have a database encoded in ISO8859-1 for your software you should consider converting both of them (database and software code) to UTF-8. This is generally easy (but of course, if your database and software are huge or critical, you should plan that conversion carefully).

Comment: But these special characters are somehow got into my db and I am using db to form the url with php(which uses ISO8859-1 ). But when the url's are formed it contains some other special character other than “ or € .

Comment: So you need to convert your DB to UTF-8. It is usually not a big deal. And the € is not part of IS8859-1

Comment: PHP is not forced to ISO-8859-1.  It is blissfully ignorant of the character set in most cases, and apparently, so were its developers for a long time.  That means you can use UTF-8 (or whatever else you like) fairly transparently, unless you specifically wish to manipulate the encoding; this is an area in which you'll find many wrong ways to do it, and few which are correct.